# Constant determinant of jacobian implies polynomial symmetry?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, polynomials

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polynomial function.  Let $F$ be of the form 
\begin{equation}
F = A + B\cdot x + (C \cdot x)\cdot x + ..., 
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n}$, etc.  Assume $det(J) = c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}, c \neq 0$, where
\begin{equation}
J = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}.
\end{equation}

I.e. the determinant of the jacobian is constant.  The constraint that $det(J) = c\,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ implies (to me) that $det(B) \neq 0$. What does $det(J)=c$ imply about the symmetry of $C$?  What does $det(J)=c$ imply about the symmetry of the function $F$?

Comment: False. Take $F =$ constant. $\forall x\in\Bbb R^n: \det J(x) = 0$ but $\det B = 0$.

Comment: Modified accordingly s.t. $c \neq 0$.